# Is it possible in Java to invoke main method in new process with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, processbuilder

Is it possible to execute a statement such as m.invoke(param1 ,param2) in a new Process.

i.e., I want to execute a Java class file by first iteratively searching for its main class using reflection and on finding the main class to invoke it in a new process.

Comment: You can start a new JVM,of course. That would probably be a new process. But I think that's not what you want. What about threads? Why a process?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig  Yes indeed you are right but then I would like you to go through my already posted problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300700/how-to-prevent-jframe-from-closing/11306236#11306236

Comment: ah...! and now you want to know how to start a new JVM? Something like Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar yourApp.jar"); should work, I think.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig No but this would not solve my problem. I can only run target application through reflection and not through jar invoke and I do not see any way of passing statement "m.invoke(param1 ,param2)" to exec() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely.

1. Find all available classes in Path
2. Introspect and find the class which has main method[check signature]
3. Use java [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)[JRE 5 +] or create a new [java.lang.Process](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to spawn the new process it should "just work"

Comment: But this is where the problem emerges. What command should be passed to the instance of process builder to execute the main method.

Comment: when you execute a jar file (or even a single class), the JVM will always execute main method.

Comment: say we have a class Foo.class (which has a static main method) and it is in the jar file bar.jar. Then to execute the jar using the static main method present in Foo class use "java -cp bar.jar Foo" as command. I assumed that java executable in there in your PATH environment variable

Comment: @sand1988 let me know if that solves your problem. +1 on your question.

Comment: @PuspenduBanerjee yes this is fine but my limitation is I cannot execute the application from jar

All I can do is to read contents of jar and then execute it using reflection and then the problem arises.. The other problem faced is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300700/how-to-prevent-jframe-from-closing/11306236#11306236 

So the only solution I could see is to invoke the application in new pocess.

Let me sum up everything:
1) I have a java application that loads a executable jar file 
2) Using reflection it invokes main of the jar
3) Now if the target application contains Frames

Comment: continued above comment 
... my application also closes on closing main frame if any of the target jar file. Although dispose on close is a solution but I cannot change the contents of target jar to be invoked. Now is there a solution meeting all my requirements